# How to combine two boolean functions in OR manner?

Tags: function, scala

Can you please help me with this:

I have 2 functions:

```
f1: Int => Boolean
f2: Int => Boolean
```

now I want to combine/merge these functions with logical OR, something like:

```
f3: Int => f1 || f2
```

so function f3 will return true only if one of functions f1 and f2 returns true

how to write such function?

thanks a lot

Comment: There's a blog post about doing this with monoids in Scalaz at http://blog.robotines.co.nz/blog/2012/11/12/combining-predicates-in-scala-with-scalaz/

Answer (score 9):

```
def f3(n:Int) = f1(n) || f2(n)
```

Comment: The problem with is that f2 may not get executed if f1 is true. This is fine just if f2 has no side effects or that is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @ViniciusMiana but that is what the OP asked for.  It is specifically what he wants to do.  Presumably he understands short-circuit boolean logic.

Comment: @barnesjd. I vote you up, your solution is perfect, but based on the doubt, I thought was worth mentioning the short-circuit.

Comment: @ViniciusMiana Thanks! I started to edit my solution to show an alternate version for your valid doubt, but I'm not confident it would work.  If we assign the result of f1 and f2 to a value and return the || result, I'm not confident that the compiler won't wipe that away.

Comment: I am not sure what the compiler will do either, however I would not bother about that, I would just add remark reminding that boolean short circuit applies and f2 might not get executed.

Answer (score 6):

So this is a good bit of infrastructure, but I've found it useful in the past to actually add boolean operations as effectively native operations on predicates.   It's one of the things I keep in my grab-bag of utility functionality, and eventually import into pretty much every project I write.

```
object PredicateUtils {

  implicit class RichPredicate[A](f: Function1[A, Boolean]) extends Function1[A, Boolean] {
    def apply(v: A) = f(v)

    def &&(g: Function1[A, Boolean]): Function1[A, Boolean] = {
      (x: A) => f(x) && g(x)
    }

    def ||(g: Function1[A, Boolean]): Function1[A, Boolean] = {
      (x: A) => f(x) || g(x)
    }

    def unary_! : Function1[A, Boolean] = {
      (x: A) => !f(x)
    }
  }
}
```

Once you've done that, then all you have to do is

```
import PredicateUtils

val f3 = f1 || f2

val f4 = !f1 && f2
```

Answer (score 3):

That would be:

`def union(f: Int => Boolean, g: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean= { x => f(x) || g(x)}`

The question here is from where comes 'x', isn't it? Well... it would be the same question as if you ask where f or g come from. You don't even think about that, those are parameters and that suffices. Same answer applies. Forget about the rest of the function. Does `x => f(x) || g(x)` make sense?  As long as f and g return boolean it does, doesn't it? So there you are.

I would say that if you read the whole function from inside out, it has obvious meaning.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
def fun_or[T](f1: T => Boolean, f2: T => Boolean)(x: T) = f1(x) || f2(x)
```

then:

```
val f3 = fun_or(f1, f2)
```

Comment: And `fun_or(f1, f2)` is more readable (or just in some way better) than `f1(n) || f2(n)` how exactly? :P

Comment: It is not hardcoded to use `f1` and `f2` as input functions. And it is generic on input type. Is it enough?

Comment: I can see there might be a case for logically combining several boolean functions into one in some specific circumstances, but there is already a *generic* method for doing this and it's just as @ErikAllik says.

Comment: I think you're using the word "generic" in ways different than most.

Answer (score 0):

examples of composing predicates: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/23/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-10-staying-dry-with-higher-order-functions.html